# How to iterate in a foreach in jsp using JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jstl-functions

I have a hashmap: `HashMap<String, array<strings>> Map = new Hashmap<>()` ;
Its keys and entries are filled as following.
University,

I want to iterate over the map in a JSP. Get the values individually.
How do I do that??

```
<c:forEach items="${map}" var="log">
            <tr>
                <td>The Uni:</td>
                <th><c:out value="${log.key}" /></th>
                <td>has following :</td>
                <td><c:out value="${log.value}" />/td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

I can't get the values using index[0] or 1 or 2.

I want the output to be like 
"the Uni : ${name of uni} has rank ${rank}  known for ${best for} ...

the param should be taken from the valueset.

Comment: log.value is an array. So you iterate over it using c:forEach. That said, if each entry of the map is supposed to be a university, with a name, a rank and a bestFor, you shouldn't have a Map. You should have a List<University>. Define classes, with named and typed properties.

Comment: @JBNizet Okk that sounds workable. Thanks